# Silent push on iOS 9 device for xCode 8 build

Tags: background, ios9, push, xcode8, silent

Does anybody known why didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler: method not called in background on iOS 9 device for app built with xCode 8?

Previously, for xCode 7, all was ok. App's background mode is On, Remote notification is also On.
Push payload looks like this:

```
{
    "aps":{
        "content-available" : 1,
        "alert" : "Hello",
        "sound" : "default",
    },
}
```

As I said, for xCode 7 all was ok both for foreground and background modes.

I've added iOS 10 pushes with UNUserNotificationCenter, and now it is ok for iOS 10 devices only, but no success for iOS 9 devices.

I've tried to add corresponding entitlements files, also to implement didReceiveRemoteNotification: method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:^(UIBackgroundFetchResult result){}];
}
```

but still the same.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you get the answer ?